# Cannot add an Android project to SVN

Tags: android, svn, android-studio

I have a project in android studio. I have enabled VCS integration, then I have imported it into SVN repository. After that, all subversion context menu options appear disabled but "Add to VCS" option. After I run that option, an error appear telling that app and all directories below are not a working copy.

How can i do it? Thanks.

Comment: Close current project and checkout your project  from the repository to a different  location and open

Answer (score 0):

Close the project  Go to option CHECKOUT FROM VERSION CONTROL and then select appropriate option and then follow the next process